# "PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class"?

Tags: apache2, php, prestashop

I have a problem that seems odd. I'm using Prestashop with a LAMP stack.
When I restart Apache, everything works fine, but after some time, I start to have those messages in the log :

> [Fri Feb 15 10:54:42 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class manufacturercore in /srv/www/my-ecommerce/classes/Manufacturer.php on line 30, referer: http://my-ecommerce.tld/fr/90421-example
>
> [Fri Feb 15 10:55:56 2013] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare class categorycore in /srv/www/my-ecommerce/classes/Category.php on line 30, referer: http://my-ecommerce.tld/fr/90599-example

If I take a look at the code in Category.php or Manufacturer.php (from Prestashop), it starts with

```
if(class_exists('CategoryCore') != true) {
    class CategoryCore extends ObjectModel {
        // Code here
    }
}
```

So now, I'm just lost.
I got an error that says the classes are redeclared, but the code seems to avoid this kind of problem.

Comment: What version of Prestashop are you running?

Comment: Thanks for the -1 without explanation, very productive!

Comment: @CyrilN. I've run into the same problem (but not with Prestashop). It happens so rarely that it's hard to replicate. Did you manage to solve it? Thanks!

Comment: Well in fact, yes ... but I don't know why and what made it works ... that's great!